# Get point on UIBezierPath e.g. most to left and bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have an UIBezierPath and want to know the coordinates of some points that lay on that path.
E.g. the rightmost point, or the point thats most to the left and to the bottom.
How could I calculate this in swift?

THX

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the bounds property from the UIBezierPath instance.

Note the following caveat:

The value in this property represents the smallest rectangle that completely encloses all points in the path, including any control points for Bézier and quadratic curves.